# Putty hides behind window with shortcut that lauched it

Tags: putty

I have a folder on my Windows 10 laptop that includes a shortcut to the Putty terminal emulator. When I double-click on the folder to open it and then double-click on the Putty shortcut my putty window opens behind the window which includes its shortcut. Why is putty hiding? If I click on the window for the folder that contains the shortcut first and then double-click on the Putty shortcut then Putty comes up in front of the folder window just as it should.

It is a mystery, at least to me. I open up putty sessions all day long and I usually have to open the folder with its shortcut first. I don't even think about it because I do it so often. Very odd.

Bobby

Comment: Have you run Malwarebytes?  Checked your startup apps.  Something is likely messing with the window order.  I know this isn't what you are asking but have you tried KiTTY instead?  I myself have had better luck with it.  MobaXTerm is even better still (but that is my opinion)

Comment: Thanks. I can check for malware. It is a company laptop so there is stuff running on it for viruses etc. I wonder if it it just my mouse bouncing and clicking an extra time or something physical like that. I have MobaXTerm for X windows but I like Putty for text. Have not heard of KiTTY. I will take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed this by running chkdsk c: /f and rebooting.

Putty does not hide behind the window that its shortcut is in anymore.

I had other issues with OneDrive and chkdsk was the recommendation for that but it seemed to fix this issue so I put it here.

Bobby